# sqlite3_open works in swift playground not swift app

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, sqlite

when I run the following code in swift playground it returned success.  When I copied it to my Xcode project it returned failure.  I figure it has something to do with the path so I googled and tried, path.cString(using: String.Encoding.utf8) but still no luck.  what I don't understand is why it works in playground but not in the app itself.

```
var db: OpaquePointer? = nil;
let path:String="/Users/williamstorey/Documents/db182.db"
if sqlite3_open(path ,&db) == SQLITE_OK {
   print("SUCCESS")
} else {
   print("FAILURE");
}
```

Comment: You can't just open any file.

Comment: You can use `NSOpenPanel` to effectively request permission to do so.

Comment: BTW, the semicolons above are not needed in Swift.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most likely problem is that your app is sandboxed and can’t just open the file there. You can build the URL dynamically, and you will get a safe file URL/path within the sandbox:

```swift
let fileURL = try! FileManager.default
    .url(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
    .appendingPathComponent("db182.db")
```

See [File System Programming Guide: The Library Directory Stores App-Specific Files](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW1). Also see [About App Sandbox](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AboutAppSandbox/AboutAppSandbox.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183).

If you really want to open files outside of the sandbox, you would need to request the user’s permission (e.g., with an [`NSOpenPanel`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsopenpanel/), as discussed in [Accessing files from the macOS App Sandbox](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/app_sandbox/accessing_files_from_the_macos_app_sandbox)).

---

A few additional observations:

1. I would capture the return code from any `sqlite3_xxx` function (such as `sqlite3_open` or `sqlite3_open_v2`) and use that to diagnose the source of the problem. You can use this return code to determine not only that it was not `SQLITE_OK`, but more importantly, what return code you actually received.
2. In the case of an error, I would also suggest retrieving the error message with `sqlite3_errmsg`. In some error conditions (esp. when preparing SQL statements), this can offer more information about what went wrong (though, admittedly, here, it is not that illuminating). But it translates the error into something easily understood (without having to pour through the [error codes](https://www.sqlite.org/rescode.html)).
3. If `sqlite3_open` fails, do not forget to `sqlite3_close`. I know it seems strange, but we must close the database whether it succeeds or not, or else you will leak memory. As the [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html) says:

   > Whether or not an error occurs when it is opened, resources associated with the [database connection](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/sqlite3.html) handle should be released by passing it to [`sqlite3_close()`](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/close.html) when it is no longer required.

   If you are storing that database connection, you might also want to `nil` that opaque pointer after when you `sqlite3_close`, to ensure that this property more accurately reflects the state of the database connection.

Thus, pulling that together, perhaps something along the lines of:

```swift
var db: OpaquePointer?

func open(
    fileURL: URL,
    flags: Int32 = SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE
) throws {
    let returnCode = sqlite3_open_v2(fileURL.path, &db, flags, nil)

    guard returnCode == SQLITE_OK else {
        let message = sqlite3_errmsg(db).flatMap { String(cString: $0) } ?? "Unknown error"
        print(#function, "error code:", returnCode, "error message:", message)
        close(db)
        throw …
    }
}

func close() {
    sqlite3_close(db)
    db = nil
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I did check the return result it was 14 SQL_CANTOPEN I completely forgot to mention that.

Comment: Yep, `SQLITE_CANTOPEN` is what you get if you try to open a file in a sandboxed environment without having asked the user for permission. So, either build the file URL/path like shown above, or if you _have_ to have the file at that URL in your question, you have to ask user permission to do so.

Comment: this was the result. /Users/williamstorey/Library/Containers/c4g.db182-osx/Data/Documents/db182.db thats not where the file is?  Im sorry the url and sandbox paradigm is new to me.

Comment: Yep, that's evidently where it will end up once you create your database using that `fileURL.path`. Sandboxing is just a paradigm in iOS/macOS programming that moves us away from a world where apps can just willy-nilly access files throughout your file system, but rather constrains them to a particular set of app-specific folders. When running properly sandboxed apps, you can be more confident that it won't be accessing/manipulating data that it shouldn't. It's a tad annoying as a developer, but as an end-user it's great as it makes our machines more secure.